# dpkg errors were encountered while processing/package is in a very bad inconsistent state

Tags: package-management, dpkg, dependencies

after the commands `apt-get update`; `apt-get install git`, `apt-get upgrade` and `apt-get -f install` etc. I get the following output about dependency problem

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
9 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/24,5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: error processing package libavahi-client3:i386 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcups2:i386:
 libcups2:i386 depends on libavahi-client3 (>= 0.6.16); however:
  Package libavahi-client3:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libcups2:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcupsfilters1:i386:
 libcupsfilters1:i386 depends on libcups2 (>= 1.7.0); however:
  Package libcups2:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libcupsfilters1:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcupsimage2:i386:
 libcupsimage2:i386 depends on libcups2 (= 1.7.2-0ubuntu1.7); however:
  Package libcups2:i386 is not configured yet.
 libcupsimage2:i386 depends on libcupsfilters1 (>= 1.0~b1); however:
  Package libcupsfilters1:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libcupsimage2:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgtk2.0-0:i386:
 libgtk2.0-0:i386 depends on libcups2 (>= 1.6.2); however:
  Package libcups2:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgtk2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgail18:i386:
 libgail18:i386 depends on libgtk2.0-0 (= 2.24.23-0ubuntu1.4); however:
  Package libgtk2.0-0:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgail18:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386:
 gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386 depends on libgtk2.0-0 (= 2.24.23-0ubuntu1.4); however:
  Package libgtk2.0-0:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ibus-gtk:i386:
 ibus-gtk:i386 depends on libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.24.5-4); however:
  Package libgtk2.0-0:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ibus-gtk:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgail-common:i386:
 libgail-common:i386 depends on libgail18 (= 2.24.23-0ubuntu1.4); however:
  Package libgail18:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgail-common:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libavahi-client3:i386
 libcups2:i386
 libcupsfilters1:i386
 libcupsimage2:i386
 libgtk2.0-0:i386
 libgail18:i386
 gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386
 ibus-gtk:i386
 libgail-common:i386
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
9 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/24,5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: error processing package libavahi-client3:i386 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcups2:i386:
 libcups2:i386 depends on libavahi-client3 (>= 0.6.16); however:
  Package libavahi-client3:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libcups2:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcupsfilters1:i386:
 libcupsfilters1:i386 depends on libcups2 (>= 1.7.0); however:
  Package libcups2:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libcupsfilters1:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcupsimage2:i386:
 libcupsimage2:i386 depends on libcups2 (= 1.7.2-0ubuntu1.7); however:
  Package libcups2:i386 is not configured yet.
 libcupsimage2:i386 depends on libcupsfilters1 (>= 1.0~b1); however:
  Package libcupsfilters1:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libcupsimage2:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgtk2.0-0:i386:
 libgtk2.0-0:i386 depends on libcups2 (>= 1.6.2); however:
  Package libcups2:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgtk2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgail18:i386:
 libgail18:i386 depends on libgtk2.0-0 (= 2.24.23-0ubuntu1.4); however:
  Package libgtk2.0-0:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgail18:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386:
 gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386 depends on libgtk2.0-0 (= 2.24.23-0ubuntu1.4); however:
  Package libgtk2.0-0:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ibus-gtk:i386:
 ibus-gtk:i386 depends on libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.24.5-4); however:
  Package libgtk2.0-0:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ibus-gtk:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgail-common:i386:
 libgail-common:i386 depends on libgail18 (= 2.24.23-0ubuntu1.4); however:
  Package libgail18:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgail-common:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libavahi-client3:i386
 libcups2:i386
 libcupsfilters1:i386
 libcupsimage2:i386
 libgtk2.0-0:i386
 libgail18:i386
 gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386
 ibus-gtk:i386
 libgail-common:i386
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: You very probably did something else to cause this problem. At this point, I would just reinstall a fresh Ubuntu, and be more careful next time.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libavahi-client3:i386`?